# VSTO: How to add custom menu to Excel File menu

Tags: excel, vsto, excel-addins

Using a ribbon component, I added a file menu, but it does not appear in Excel after execution, but it appears when I add a button.

1.Is it possible to add menu component to file menu?
[image]

2.When I add the button it shows up under Add-ins, is it possible to show that before Info (pls refer the image)?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using VB or C# as the project type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it by using the Ribbon XML and inserting the custom tab after the `TabRecent` "Open" tab. The [Microsoft Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=50745) only goes up to Office 2016. I could not get `TabInfo` to work.

Here are the references I found.

- http://youpresent.co.uk/customising-powerpoint-2016-backstage-view/
- https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win005.htm

#### Backstage References:

- Home = `PlaceTabHome`
- New = `TabOfficeStart`
- Open = `TabRecent`
- Info = `TabInfo`
- Save = `FileSave`
- Save As = `TabSave`
- History = `HistoryTab`
- Print =  `TabPrint`
- Share = `TabShare`, `ShareDocument`
- Export = `TabPublish`
- Publish = `Publish2Tab`
- Close = `FileClose`
- Account = `TabHelp`
- Feedback = `TabOfficeFeedback`
- Options = `TabOptions`, `ApplicationOptionsDialog`

---

#### XML Ribbon Code

```
<ribbon startFromScratch="false">
</ribbon>
<backstage>
  <tab id="grpMyMenu" label="Annotate" insertAfterMso="TabRecent" visible="true" firstColumnMaxWidth="500">
    <firstColumn>
      <group id="grpOne" label="Microsoft Snipping Tool">
        <primaryItem>
          <button
                id="btnSnippingTool"
                label="Snipping Tool"
                onAction="OnAction"
                getImage="GetButtonImage"
                screentip="Microsoft Snipping Tool"
                supertip="Snipping Tool is a screenshot utility included in Microsoft Windows. It can take screenshots of an open window, rectangular areas, a free-form area, or the entire screen."
                />
        </primaryItem>
        <topItems>
          <layoutContainer id="layoutOne" layoutChildren="horizontal">
            <labelControl id="ebox2" label="Snipping Tool is a screenshot utility included in Microsoft Windows. It can take screenshots of an open window, rectangular areas, a free-form area, or the entire screen." />
          </layoutContainer>
        </topItems>
      </group>
      <group id="grpTwo" label="Microsoft Problem Steps Recorder" >
        <primaryItem>
          <button
                id="btnProblemStepRecorder"
                label="Record Steps"
                onAction="OnAction"
                getImage="GetButtonImage"
                screentip="Microsoft Problem Steps Recorder"
                supertip="Problem Steps Recorder or PSR records the actions you take on your computer which you can then send to the person or group helping you with your computer problem."
                />
        </primaryItem>
        <topItems>
          <labelControl id="ebox3" label="Problem Steps Recorder or PSR records the actions you take on your computer which you can then send to the person or group helping you with your computer problem."/>
        </topItems>
      </group>
    </firstColumn>
  </tab>
</backstage>
```

#### C# Code

```
    public void OnAction(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        string filePath = string.Empty;
        switch (control.Id)
        {
            case "btnSnippingTool":
                if (System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
                {
                    filePath = @"C:\Windows\sysnative\SnippingTool.exe";
                }
                else
                {
                    filePath = @"C:\Windows\system32\SnippingTool.exe";
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
                break;
            case "btnProblemStepRecorder":
                filePath = @"C:\Windows\System32\psr.exe";
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
                break;
        }
    }

    public System.Drawing.Bitmap GetButtonImage(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        switch (control.Id)
        {
            case "btnProblemStepRecorder":
                return Properties.Resources.problem_steps_recorder;
            case "btnSnippingTool":
                return Properties.Resources.snipping_tool;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

#### Screenshot of File Tab "Backstage"

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much, the time and effort you spent reacting to the post are appreciated.

Comment: No worries, anytime. I also have a few example projects if that helps. https://github.com/Excel-projects